# How to remove the value from this NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

Hello everyone i have a dictionary  value when i nslog returns the following below :

> NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1
>   options:0 error:nil];
>                DLog(@"RESPONSE ====== %@",dict);

```
{
    errors =     (
                {
            "@msg" = "already exists";
            "@title" = "title";
        }
    ); }
```

How can i extract msg key data from it?

Comment: uh, what do you mean by extract ? Do you want to get the data corresponding to this key, or do you want to remove it from the dictionary ?

Comment: I have edited the question above please check :) Data corresponding

Comment: Why you didn't bother your self and read the NSDictionary Class Reference   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = dict[@"errors"];
NSDictionary *error1 = array[0];
NSString *msg = error1[@"@msg"];
```

`NSString *msg` would now contain `already exists`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it like this:

```
NSString *msg = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"@msg"];
```

and remove like this:

```
[myDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"@msg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary dic2 = [dict objectforKey:@"errors"];
NSString* msg = [dict2 objectForKey:@"@msg"];
```